# Magento 2.2 CMS pages missing URL KEY

Tags: magento2.2

I have three stores in Magento 2.2 with different languages. For this i am translating all the pages. Before there was URL KEY for pages where i can copy the identifier and assign it to the specific stores but i am missing URL KEY here. What am i doing wrong or is there any other way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the page URL key under the "Search Engine Optimization" tab in the CMS page edit section.

Comment: Thank you :) It helps

Comment: you're welcome.

Comment: Is there any way to have same identifier for a page in all scopes?

So for example i have 3 stores that is in english, german and dutch.

Now i want to have one page with different translations and different URLS but with same identifier. When i call the identifier from phtml i can get the respective page (translation).

for example. 
contact page -> identifier: contact -> Translation:English -> URL:English (contact)
contact page -> identifier: contact -> Translation:German -> URL:german (kontakt)

and so on.

Comment: No, this is not possible with the same CMS page. You can create another page for specific store view with your URL key.